# Миллисекунды в PHP

Tags: php

В пхп, например, есть номер `1.319983091E+12 (time() / 1000)`, миллисекунды, аналог `new Date().getTime()`. Вопрос: как перевести номер в нормальный? То есть, например, 1319982493275, или же другой способ узнать милисекунды?

Answer (score 2):

[`microtime(1)`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.microtime.php) выдаст время во `float`. Дальше, думаю, разберетесь)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    list($a, $b) = explode(" ", microtime());
    $millis = $b * 1000 + round($a * 1000);
    echo $millis;
    // или проще:
    echo round(microtime(true) * 1000);
?>
```

Comment: Сами ошибку найдете?)

Comment: Хотелось бы конечно самому) добавил `echo microtime(true);` и это выдало ровно в 1000 раз меньшее значение, чем предыдущее, что вроде бы логично, требуются ведь миллисекунды. Например `1319984792547` и `1319984792.5475`.

Comment: Все, мой косяк, признаю. Почему-то думал, что $a будет целым.

А это, `round(microtime(1)*1000)` чем хуже?)

Comment: Да, я потом подумал, что так адекватнее будет...) Просто сам никогда миллисекунды не узнавал, а разбиением пользовался. Разбиение только показывает, где секунды, а где остаток... Я добавил в свой ответ, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Пишут ([http://php.su/learnphp/datatypes/?integer](http://)), что в PHP целые обычно длиной 32 бита (от –2 147 483 648 до 2 147 483 647).

Поэтому время в миллисекундах считая от 1.1.1970 в виде целого числа не может быть представлено.

Comment: Может быть до лонга удлинняются... Так или иначе это число появляется на экране через `echo`.

Comment: round(microtime(true) * 1000) это float 64-битный IEEE формат. Понятно, что там миллисекунды помещаются.

В каком формате   echo (**PHP** дурацкая документация) выводит float я найти не смог. Видимо (если дробной части нет (round !)) как цепочку десятичных цифр.

Comment: PHP загадочен...)

Comment: мда, гугл уже не тот